# How can I locate the frames of a spritesheet PNG based on this PLIST data?

Tags: sprites, cocos2d, spritesheet, png

Someone asked me to reskin a certain game. Now he only sent me the whole sprite PNG and PLIST files of the sprites. He instructed me to rename each sprite with the same name corresponding to each original sprite.

The problem is, he gave me the whole sprite sheet instead of each individual sprite and the PLIST. Now yes, I can read the PNG filenames from the PLIST, but I cannot rename the reskin sprites I did because I'm not sure which sprite is boy_gun_3_3.png; there are multiple guns, I don't know which is which.

Is there a way to extract individual accurately named individual PNG files from the single sprite sheet using the PLIST?

Comment: It sounds like you already know the solution.  Is this just a problem of automation?  If so, the answer is to program it.

Comment: no, it's not a programming problem, it's a problem of how to extract the sprites from PNG if I only have a PNG sprite sheet and a .PLIST file.

Comment: But the plist has the names and locations in it, and that's the information you need?

Comment: Post a sample of the .plist please.

Comment: Could you solve this and how?

Answer (score 1):

A `.png` is a generic image format, and a `.plist` is a generic key-value "property list" format. Neither are *inherently* concerned with sprites or sprite sheets.

That means the answer to this question depends highly on what's in files -- primarily the `.plist` file.

Normally any sort of spritesheet metadata (which is what your `.plist` sounds like) has both sprite frame names and the positions of each frame. Or something similar, like sequence names and sequence boundaries, where each frame in a sequence is a fixed size.

If you have this size and position information available in the sprite, you can interpret it to know how to extract the individual sprites associated with the individual names. If you do not have this information in the `.plist`, you probably can't correlate the names in the property list file to the frames in the image.

(It's possible that the organization of the file is such that each sprite is a fixed size and they match 1:1 in a certain order (for example, you look at individual frames from left-to-right, top-to-bottom, and that traversal of the `.png` corresponds to a document-order traversal of the `.plist`), in which case you also have sufficient information to do the correlation you want, but that's going to depend on the author of the data.)